# MSSQL Search in Json with inner array

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I have a table, with a JSON column named ExtraTaskData.
The JSON looks like that:

```
[   
{
    "Type": "checkbox",
    "IsActive": true,
    "Name": "english",
    "Lang": "eng"   
},
{
    "CreateOrder": {
        "orderNumber": 0,
        "tasks": [
           {
           "tempOrderNumber": "78cf0ba2-4b83-4286-82c0-7b7b44ceec52",
           "targetLanguage": "heb",
           "productCode": 0,
           "productId": null
           }
        ]
    }   
} 
]
```

I need to search the value of "tempOrderNumber", which is inside an array "tasks" that is inside "CreateOrder".
I tried the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM [Traffic].[TrafficTasks] a
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (a.[ExtraTaskData]) as b
WHERE JSON_VALUE(b.[value],'$.CreateOrder.tasks.tempOrderNumber') = @SearchValue
```

but no luck.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there can be multiple tasks, and mutiple order tempOrderNumbers you could do this:

```sql
SELECT TT.* --Replace with actual columns
FROM [Traffic].[TrafficTasks] TT --"a" is for TrafficTasks?
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (TT.[ExtraTaskData]) 
     WITH (CreateOrder nvarchar(MAX) AS JSON) CO
     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(CO.CreateOrder)
                 WITH (tasks nvarchar(MAX) AS JSON) t
     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(t.tasks)
                 WITH (tempOrderNumber uniqueidentifier) tON
WHERE tON.tempOrderNumber = @SearchValue;
```

Answer (score 1):

The statement depends on the structure of the input JSON and if the `"CreateOrder"` JSON object is inside the second item of the stored JSON array, the following statement is an option:

Table:

```
SELECT t.*
INTO TrafficTasks
FROM (VALUES
   ('[
   {
      "Type":"checkbox",
      "IsActive":true,
      "Name":"english",
      "Lang":"eng"
   },
   {
      "CreateOrder":{
         "orderNumber":0,
         "tasks":[
            {
               "tempOrderNumber":"78cf0ba2-4b83-4286-82c0-7b7b44ceec52",
               "targetLanguage":"heb",
               "productCode":0,
               "productId":null
            }
         ]
      }
   }
]')
) t (ExtraTaskData)
```

Statement:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM [TrafficTasks] t
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (t.[ExtraTaskData], '$[1].CreateOrder.tasks') WITH (
   tempOrderNumber uniqueidentifier '$.tempOrderNumber'  
) j
WHERE j.tempOrderNumber = @SearchValue
```

If `CreateOrder` is not inside the second item of the stored JSON array, a more general approach is the following statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM [TrafficTasks] t
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (t.ExtraTaskData, '$') WITH (
   tasks nvarchar(max) 'lax $.CreateOrder.tasks' AS JSON
) j1
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (j1.tasks, '$') WITH (
   tempOrderNumber uniqueidentifier '$.tempOrderNumber'
) j2
WHERE j2.tempOrderNumber = @SearchValue
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't find results.
Value is: '78cf0ba2-4b83-4286-82c0-7b7b44ceec52'

Comment: @AaYy, I understand, it seems that `CreateOrder` is not always inside the second item of the stored JSON. In this case you'll need a different statement with one additional `OPENJSON()` and apply operator.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json_value()` directly with the correct path:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM [Traffic].[TrafficTasks] a
where json_value(a.[ExtraTaskData], '$[1].CreateOrder.tasks[0].tempOrderNumber') = @SearchValue;
```